# What is the difference between CUDA desktop and notebook release?

Tags: cuda

I am developing for CUDA on a notebook (for now) using the CUDA notebook release. Later I will want to move to the desktop. I want to understand what are the differences between the two releases? I did not find any information on Nvidia website about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the bundled Driver - notebooks use drivers that are different from desktop drivers. The CUDA libraries should be the same.

Comment: Which naturally gives rise to the question: In which way do the bundled Driver differ between the two releases?